# Exibir dados de API React Native

Tags: json, api, react-native, axios, react-hooks

Olá Dev's Sou novo em RN, estou tentando mostrar o retorno de um json, mas não consigo acessar pelo identificador na tela, somente no console.

export default function Funcional() {
const [data, setData] = useState([]);
const [refreshing, setRefreshing] = useState(true);

useEffect(() => {
async function loadInicial() {

```
  let id = 'XXX';
  var retorno = await getUser().then((value) => {
    let token = JSON.parse(value);
    console.log(token)
    return token
    }, (error) => {
    console.log(error) 
  });

  const response = await api.get('users/'+id,{ params: { jwt: retorno.jwt } })

  console.log(response.data)

  setData(JSON.stringify(response.data));
  
  //setData(JSON.stringify(response.data.data)); Tentei assim tambem
}

loadInicial();
```

}, []);

// Assim Não funciona
return(

{data.nome}

),

//Assim mostra todo Array
return(

{data}

),

//JSON que está retornando
{"data": {"nome": "José Paulo"}}

No console consigo imprimir a chave sem problemas

Comment: Consegui Galera Tava Vacilando, Retire o StringiFy() e funcionou.

Answer (score 0):

Talvez o problema é que você está convertendo usando **JSON.stringify()** e passando para o estado.

Tente somente passar para o estado o **response.data** sem converter-lo.

Exemplo:

```
setData(response.data);
```

Comment: Perfeito, Funcionou. Obg!